# How do I create a signature with Web3.js which EthCrypto can process properly?

Tags: web3js, cryptography

I am building a Dapp. In the front end, I use Web3.js to generate a signature with Metamask:

```
const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});
const account = accounts[0];
const signatureHash = await web3.value.eth.personal.sign('Signature verification for video file encryption', account);
```

In the back end, I attempt to recover the address with EthCrypto:

```
const address2 = EthCrypto.recover(signature, EthCrypto.hash.keccak256('Signature verification for video file encryption'))
```

This returns an address which does not match the original address.

Also, attempting to recover a public key and then an address from it matches address2 above, but not the original address!

```
const publicKey = EthCrypto.recoverPublicKey(
     signature,
     EthCrypto.hash.keccak256('Signature verification for video file encryption')
    );
```

How can I generate a signature in the front end which EthCrypto will process properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to calculate the `keccak256` hash with the 'Ethereum signed message' format:

```js
const address2 = EthCrypto.recover(
  signature,
  EthCrypto.hash.keccak256(
    "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" + message.length + message
  )
);
```

Your data will look like this:

```
Ethereum Signed Message:
48Signature verification for video file encryption
```

So you calculate the `keccak256` hash of that.

Check the docs:

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-personal.html#sign
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-accounts.html#recover

Check the `EIP`: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712

Comment: The message.length is just the length of the original message string?

Comment: The EthCrypto documentation gives this example:

`const signer = EthCrypto.recoverPublicKey(
      '0xc04b809d8f33c46ff80c44ba58e866ff0d5..', // signature
      EthCrypto.hash.keccak256('foobar') // message hash
  );`

`"\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n"` does not appear.

Comment: Yes. The length is the length of the original message.
I don't know why `EthCrypto` does not include the `\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n` part in their documentation. But anyways, `web3.value.eth.personal.sign` prepends `EthCrypto` does not include the `\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n` to the message before hashing it. So, the message hash that you should share is the one with that prepended, so other libraries that will recover the address from the signature and hash will recover it as expected.

Comment: What you need to keep in mind is that when you sign a message with `web3.value.eth.personal.sign` or any other library that implements `eip-712`, your message is not exactly your original message anymore, it has the `\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n` data and you have to consider that if you need to create a `keccak256` hash of your message that will be related to a signature.